# How to Log Barcode Scanner Output?

Tags: bash, powershell, barcode-scanner

Is there a way to log a barcode scanner's output?

We have an issue with our barcode scanner. 
I can't explain it well so I will just leave a picture here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMPzz.jpg

Unfortunately, this issue happens intermittently and the scanner does have carriage return set after every input (so that it can automatically jump to the next text box field).

We have 2 hypothesis for this issue:
1) Bug in the form
2) User scans faster than the PC can have time to process the carriage return

Are there anyway to have a script/service that log the output of the scanner into a txt file and at the same time enable the user to use the form normally?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that "2) User scans faster than the PC can have time to process the carriage return".

Using the setting barcode, adjust the barcode reading interval called "Good Read Delay" or "Reread Delay" etc. to a longer interval.

Comment: I'd like to think so as well. Are there anyway to prove this?

Comment: It is conceivable that programs such as applying a workload to the CPU/memory/DISK on the computer side are operated at the same time.